# Chime sdk throw "OverconstrainedError: Invalid constraint" with some iOS devices

Tags: angular, exception, ionic-framework, aws-chime-sdk

I'm working with a project that use chime sdk js 3.14.0 + ionic 6 to build a video call feature.
On production, I keep see logs that said "OverconstrainedError: Invalid constraint" but have no idea what's causing it nor what behavior the user would see when this was thrown. By the way, the message was from "audioInputFailed" event. Recently, I see the error mostly come from iOS 16.

I tried to reproduce the error, play around with audio on/off, change input devices with a real device iOS 16 but no luck.

Any helps, it would be a great help even only with how to reproduce the error?